# How to get fan-gate implemented for php Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to create a facebook fangate tab.

i am using this code

```
<?php 

    // create the Facebook Graph SDK object
    require_once('facebook.php');
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'=>'xxx', // replace with your value
        'secret'=>'xxxxx' // replace with your value
            ));
    $signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    // Inspect the signed request
    if($signedRequest['page']['liked'] == 1){
        echo 'pageid ' + $signed_request["page"]["id"]; 
        include('like.php');

    } else {
        echo 'pageid ' + $signed_request["page"]["id"]; 
        include('noLike.php');

    }
?>
```

But it dosnt seem to work, the page id displays as zero. it always displays the nolike.php file.

I have also tried this code

```
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];





?>


<?php
if($like_status){
       include('like.php');
    }else{
        include('noLike.php');
 }

?>
```

This also only shows the noLike.php file

here is a like to the page
http://www.facebook.com/pages/BigDawg-Labs/166258126793251?sk=app_280260608708912

Do you have any ideas why i cannot `$signed_request["page"]["liked"]` always evaluates to false

Comment: `print_r($signed_request)` please.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what print_r on signed_request actually displays too.

Comment: I fixed it, it was to do with the fact i was pointing facebook at www.example.com/facebookPage/ and not www.example.com/facebookPage/index.php